# What is the nginx equivalent to this mod_rewrite rule?

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, wordpress

My wordpress is telling me to update my htaccess file to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm using nginx, and I have this but it doesn't work:

```
 location / {
            root   /home/mywebsite/public;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;

            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ~(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wordpress will keep complaining about not having htaccess as it can't understand why anyone would not use Apache. If your site works then you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

try changing it to this;

```
   location / {
       root   /home/mywebsite/public;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

   }
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

Answer (score -1):

Its works Perfectly.

And for Enable PHP

## pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

```
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about this magic?